# How to change TextInputLayout color in android?

Tags: android, android-textinputlayout

Hi I am new for android and in my app I am using TextInputLayout fields.

I set the EditText border color and I don't want to set edit-text background color but according to my below code, when I tap on the "SIGN UP" button edittext background color displays as red.

How can we change this background color?

### edittext_background:-

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" >

    <solid android:color="@android:color/white" />

    <stroke
        android:width="1dip"
        android:color="@android:color/holo_purple" />

    <padding android:left="5dp"
        android:top="5dp"
        android:right="5dp"
        android:bottom="5dp"/>

</shape>
```

### styles:-

```
 <style name="TextAppearance.App.TextInputLayout" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/splahbgcolor</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">14sp</item>
    </style>
```

### main.xml:-

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:paddingRight="20dp"
        android:paddingTop="60dp">

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/input_layout_name"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:hintTextAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.App.TextInputLayout">

            <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText
                android:id="@+id/input_name"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:background="@drawable/edittext_background"
                android:ems="10"
                android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                android:padding="8dp"
                android:textColor="@color/splahbgcolor"
                android:hint="@string/hint_name" />

        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

### MainActivity:-

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Toolbar toolbar;
    private EditText inputName, inputEmail, inputPassword;
    private TextInputLayout inputLayoutName, inputLayoutEmail, inputLayoutPassword;
    private Button btnSignUp;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        inputLayoutName = (TextInputLayout) findViewById(R.id.input_layout_name);
        inputLayoutEmail = (TextInputLayout) findViewById(R.id.input_layout_email);
        inputLayoutPassword = (TextInputLayout) findViewById(R.id.input_layout_password);

        inputName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.input_name);
        inputEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.input_email);
        inputPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.input_password);

        btnSignUp = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_signup);

        inputName.addTextChangedListener(new MyTextWatcher(inputName));
        inputEmail.addTextChangedListener(new MyTextWatcher(inputEmail));
        inputPassword.addTextChangedListener(new MyTextWatcher(inputPassword));

        btnSignUp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                submitForm();
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Validating form
     */
    private void submitForm() {

        if (!validateName()) {
            return;
        }

        if (!validateEmail()) {
            return;
        }

        if (!validatePassword()) {
            return;
        }

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Thank You!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    private boolean validateName() {

        if (inputName.getText().toString().trim().isEmpty()) {
            inputLayoutName.setError(getString(R.string.err_msg_name));
            requestFocus(inputName);
            return false;

        } else {
            inputLayoutName.setErrorEnabled(false);
        }

        return true;
    }

    private boolean validateEmail() {

        String email = inputEmail.getText().toString().trim();

        if (email.isEmpty() || !isValidEmail(email)) {
            inputLayoutEmail.setError(getString(R.string.err_msg_email));
            requestFocus(inputEmail);
            return false;
        } else {
            inputLayoutEmail.setErrorEnabled(false);
        }

        return true;
    }

    private boolean validatePassword() {

        if (inputPassword.getText().toString().trim().isEmpty()) {
            inputLayoutPassword.setError(getString(R.string.err_msg_password));
            requestFocus(inputPassword);
            return false;
        } else {
            inputLayoutPassword.setErrorEnabled(false);
        }

        return true;
    }

    private static boolean isValidEmail(String email) {

        return !TextUtils.isEmpty(email) && android.util.Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(email).matches();
    }

    private void requestFocus(View view) {

        if (view.requestFocus()) {
            getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_VISIBLE);
        }
    }

    private class MyTextWatcher implements TextWatcher {

        private View view;

        private MyTextWatcher(View view) {
            this.view = view;
        }

        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

        }

        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

        }

        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

            switch (view.getId()) {

                case R.id.input_name:
                    validateName();
                    break;

                case R.id.input_email:
                    validateEmail();
                    break;

                case R.id.input_password:
                    validatePassword();
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: change the accent color

Comment: What is the value of `splahbgcolor` color.??

Comment: where can i chnage i am not understand

Comment: this is my splashbgcolor ===>EF4836

Comment: can you post the code of `Onclick` of `Button`.

Comment: can i share my sample project to u?

Comment: very small one then u can easily find my mistack

Comment: yes i posted see once

Comment: @Krish The error is display in the box because you change the box size In real there is only a line for `EditText` but you have create box so this is apply to whole box.

Comment: then how can i modified this?

Answer (score 0):

use theme instead of hintTextAppearance

```
 <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/input_layout_name"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           app:hintTextAppearance="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:theme="@style/TextAppearance>
```

your style

```
 <style name="TextAppearance" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/splahbgcolor</item>
        <item name="android:textColorHint">@color/splahbgcolor</item>
    </style>
```

Comment: i am getting exception

Comment: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                 java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Can't convert to color: type=0x2

Comment: can you please change your style name like for TextAppearance.App.TextInputLayout to style_textlayout for now  and check @Krish

Comment: u mean  <style name="style_textlayout" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance">?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115185/discussion-between-krish-and-kdeogharkar).

Comment: I am updating my answer.

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR version:**
Call `inputName.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.edittext_background);`after every call to `inputLayoutName.setError(getString(R.string.err_msg_name));`

**Longer version:**
This happens because when you call **setError(errormsg)** on `TextInputlayout` internally(in TextInputLayout's code) this method after setting up your `Errorview` calls following method:
    `updateEditTextBackground();`

Inside the `updateEditTextBackground()` method of TextInputLayout class, your editText's background color is changed using following line:

```
if (mErrorShown && mErrorView != null) {
        // Set a color filter of the error color
        editTextBackground.setColorFilter(
                AppCompatDrawableManager.getPorterDuffColorFilter(
                        mErrorView.getCurrentTextColor(), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN));
    }
```

As a result your Edittext's background color changes to red color (This is picked up from `Errorview's` default textAppearance style from the framework).

Only workaround possible in your case would be to  add below line after all your `setError` methods in if clause:

```
inputName.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.edittext_background);
```

`validateName()` method:

```
   private boolean validateName() {

    if (inputName.getText().toString().trim().isEmpty()) {
        inputLayoutName.setError(getString(R.string.err_msg_name));
        inputName.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.edittext_background);
        requestFocus(inputName);
        return false;

    } else {
        inputLayoutName.setErrorEnabled(false);
    }

    return true;
}
```

Possibly only workaround to your problem at the moment.
Not sure if this is the appropriate way to handle custom Edittext background situation.